# Can Intent be used to access ContentProvider?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver

I am new  in Android developing.

If i want to access data in a ContentProvider, so I have to use the ContentResolver.

Can Intent be used access to ContentProvider ? If yes, how to use it ?

Comment: You are familiar with intents? Please show how you would like to use one for a content provider.

Comment: No , i dont think so

Comment: Please let me know if you have still any problems.